# Elseif not working in Wordpress php file

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function wpse_load_scripts_styles() {

if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) ) { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-home', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylehome.css' );
}

elseif ( is_page ( 'shop' ) ) { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-shop', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styleshop.css' );
}

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_scripts_styles' );
```

Hello, I am trying to add custom css to different pages of my site.  The first if statement works, but the elseif statement does not work :(  The page is called 'shop' and '/styleshop.css' is in same folder as '/stylehome.css'

If anyone could see any error in the code, I would gladly appreciate it.  Thank you so much!

ps, if i change the elseif to else {...}, it works.

Comment: Try different syntax - if() : ... elseif() : ... endif; Maybe it will help. Your code looks ok.

Comment: What happens when you put elseif on the same line as the closing curly bracket from the if? (i.e. `} elseif ( ... ) {`?)

Comment: the syntax is [correct](), so the first question to ask, really, is "what are you testing for". First, check to make sure `is_page` even gets called in the second instance (I suspect it is) and then check what its internal variables report (I suspect *not* "shop" but something else, making it return `false`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `else` works but `elseif` does not, then that means that both of expressions that you are testing must be returning "falsey" values.

You can test this by adding the following code into your page:

```
<pre>
homepage?
<?php var_dump((bool) is_page('homepage')); ?><br>
shop?
<?php var_dump((bool) is_page('shop')); ?>
</pre>
```

`(bool)` will convert the result of `is_page()` into a boolean value (it probably is anyway but for the sake of brevity it's worth forcing it) to make it easier for you to see what is going on.